# xpath to find node by element and attribute containing a child element with a certain id

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

In c# I'm trying to find an `xpath` expression that will get me the value of a `<property>` element with id of `ROBEGIN` whose parent is `<option>` and that parent contains a child `<property>` with id of `CEProductID` and value of `5832198a-7cec-ea11-a817-000d3a191efa`. The expected value I want to get is **777**. Here is an xml fragment from a large xml file:

```
...
<option id="Whatever">
   <property id="CEProductID">5832198a-7cec-ea11-a817-000d3a191efa</property>
   ...
   <property id="ROBEGIN">777</property>
</option>
...
```

Important: For the `<option>` to be a correct match it must contain BOTH the child elements shown above, with correct `id` attribute values and correct element value of `CEProductID`. If it has one or the other matching `<property>` but not both, it should be ignored.

I have tried the following (and other permutations of it) without success:

```
xmlNode.SelectNodes($"//property[@id='CEProductID']='5832198a-7cec-ea11-a817-000d3a191efa'");
```

Admittedly, the above line of c# code (even if it worked) would have only gotten me the `CEProductID` `<property>` element, with which I could go programmatically up to the parent, and back down into the properties to see if `<ROBEGIN>` exists, and if it does, grab the value. But that seems super inefficient and I think xpath has more power than that.

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should get you exactly what you need:**

```
//property [@id = 'ROBEGIN' and
    parent::option [property
        [@id = 'CEProductID' and text() = '5832198a-7cec-ea11-a817-000d3a191efa' ]]
]/text()
```

**Let's break it down:**

- `//property` descend to any node named `property`
- `[@id='ROBEGIN'` which has this matching attribute `id`
- `and parent::option` and has a parent node named `option`
- which in turn has `[property` child node
- which in turn has `[@id='CEProductID'` attribute
- and that node's inner text matches `text()='5832198a-7cec-ea11-a817-000d3a191efa'`
- `]]]/text()` going back to the original node, take the inner text

**Result:**

- `777`

Comment: Charlieface, fantastic answer and works great. Thanks for your concise response.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to match option tag with two properties as stated in your question and then go down that second ROBEGIN and extract the inner html.

```
//option[property[@id='CEProductID'] and property[@id='ROBEGIN']]/property[@id='ROBEGIN']/text()

# 777
```

Comment: BcK, looks like a great answer, but missing the guid which needed to be part of it. So I upvoted you but awarded Charlie the right answer. Thanks much for your time and attention.

Comment: No problem, I thought it was a bit self-explanatory but you are right.